# where does go log the errors?

Tags: logging, go

I'm using the [log](http://golang.org/pkg/log/) packages and I'm wondering what's the default destination of the log data. I can't find it anywhere. Do I need a io writer and specifically call it after each log or how is it supposed to work ?

Answer (score 6):

It should be `stdErr`, as in [line 58 of `log.go`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/log/log.go?s=8605:8649#L58):

```
var std = New(os.Stderr, "", LstdFlags)
```

So package methods like `Fatal()` uses std by default:

```
// Fatal is equivalent to Print() followed by a call to os.Exit(1).
func Fatal(v ...interface{}) {
    std.Output(2, fmt.Sprint(v...))
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

The blog post "[How to write Go packages coders will love](https://vividcortex.com/blog/2013/12/03/go-idiom-package-and-object/) " (by Baron Schwartz) references that technique:

> One of the patterns I've found in the standard Go library is what I call package-and-object. (That's my own name; maybe I'm reinventing or naming something already known by another name.) You can see this idiom in several packages. It makes these packages a delight to use.
>
> **The essence of the idiom is that you design a type with methods as usual, and then you also place matching functions at the package level itself. These functions simply delegate to a default instance of the type that's a private package-level variable, created in an `init()` function**.
>
> To take a look at the default logging functionality, for example, you can just import the `log` package and then write things like `log.Print()`. It's super-concise and handy, and it does the right thing.
> Want to customize it? Make your own `log.Logger` variable, and set its properties.

---

Note that, with [Go 1.13](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.13#log) (Q3 2019), the new [`Writer()` function](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/log/#Writer) returns the output destination for the standard logger.

Comment: still don't get it ... I'm running go routines and can't find the log

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat the articles I mention illustrate that you can just `import log`, and use directly `log.xxx()`: you don't have to "find log", you can just import and use it.